# Can I create a custom list of values like ACL in Varnish 4?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm using Varnish version 4. I'd like to know if VCL allows a custom and reusable list of values like `ACL`. I want to use it to check against visitors' cookies. If he is a moderator, don't serve cached content.

Cookie String:

```
   session=9urt2jipvkq77brfrf; UserID=158
```

Code:

```
   acl moderator{
       "158";
       "114";
   }

   sub vcl_recv {

      set req.http.UserID = regsub(req.http.Cookie,".*UserID=(\d+).*","\1"); // 158

      if(req.http.UserID ~ moderator){ // 158 found in the moderator list

          return(pass);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no

ACL (access control list) is only used for specifying different IPs/hosts.

However you can use a VMOD to accomplish this. Checkout [Variable](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/variable)

It has some basic functions for setting and getting variables.

```
set("my_var", "this is the value")
set req.http.x-my-var = get("my_var")
```

There is also some more advanced functions, like setting multiple variables from a single string using regex.

```
variable.regset("ttl:d=\1s,grace:d=\2s", "^(?:.*,)?max-age=([0-9]+)(?:+([0-9]+))", beresp.http.Surrogate-Control);
set beresp.ttl = variable.get_duration("ttl");
set beresp.grace = variable.get_duration("grace");
```

`ttl` is the name of the variable, `grace` is the name of the second variable

`\1` & `\2` are simple back-references to the regex

`:d` specifies the type, in this case *duration*

**Your list of user id:s**

You could just set them in a comma separated string

```
set("moderators", ",158,114,") //Notice the starting and ending comma-sign

if(","+req.http.UserID+"," ~ get("moderators")){

     return(pass);
 }
```

Comment: I think this solution is not correct.That way UIDs such as 1, 5, 8, 15, 58, etc. would be handled also as moderators.

Comment: That's true, I've edited the regex slightly to fix this